# Recursively recombining split key/values pairs

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

This is making my head hurt, if there are any generous javascript gurus here, i would greatly appreciate some help

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

Given this:

```
var keys   = ["Age", "Name", "Photos", { "Friends": ["FirstName", "LastName"] }];
var values = [ [31, "Bob", ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"], [ ["Bob", "Hope"], ["Foo", "Bar"] ] ], [21, "Jane"] ["4.jpg", "5.jpg"], [ ["Mr", "T"],["Foo", "Bar"] ] ];
```

I would like to get back this:

```
var object = [
                {
                "Age"    : 31,
                "Name"   : "Bob",
                "Photos" : ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"]
                "Friends": [ 
                               {
                                   "FirstName": "Bob",
                                   "LastName" : "Hope"
                                },
                                {
                                    "FirstName": "Foo",
                                    "LastName" : "Bar"
                                }
                ] 
            },
            {
                "Age"     : 21,
                "Name"    : "Jane",
                "Photos" : ["4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
                "Friends": [ 
                               {
                                   "FirstName": "Mr",
                                   "LastName" : "T"
                                },
                                {
                                    "FirstName": "Foo",
                                    "LastName" : "Bar"
                                }
                ] 
            }               
];
```

It's for a spec proposal (JsonR) i'm working on [here](https://github.com/itechnology/JsonRaw)

Currently i'm able to (almost) work this out (but not any deeper..):

```
var keys   = ["Age", "Name", "Photos" ];
var values = [ [31, "Bob", ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"]], [21, "Jane", ["4.jpg", "5.jpg"]] ];
```

Thank's for any feedback or help!

Comment: Where did `"Pseudo"` come from? I'd've expected `"Name"` there...

Comment: You know there are already several compression scripts avail for JSON, right? (like JSONH, JSONR, etc..). And you also know that gzipping data transfers makes such compression obsolete?

Comment: @Amandan: Corrected the name/pseudo thing ..leftovers from multiple snippets, tnx

Comment: @David no i do not know those but will have a look. As for gzip. I already use a simplified version of what I'm asking an answer to and we do use gzip. But that doesn't change that when returning 20k of collections in gzip, the above will still render that to almost half the size, and at 400million request/day ..savings add up quick

Comment: @David—it's an exercise in converting data in arrays to an object, nothing to do with compression.

Comment: @David Tnx for the info, i looked at JsonH. But JsonH seems like nothing more that a flat json array, and is pretty much what i've been using for the past 5 years client/server side. The thing is that i'd like to be able to move beyond flat arrays.

Comment: @Robert: Are you looking for CSV? Would add even a bit more "compression".

Comment: Using an object for the `Friends` key doesn't make much sense to me. `["Friends","FirstName","LastName"]` might be easier.

Comment: @Bergi No, it should stay 100% json compatible. And adding friends to the name array, you would have no way to differentiate what is what anymore. It's just a collection of objects/arrays, with their keys removed, and we need to be able to map them back. Peter Olsons reply is perfect !

Comment: @Robert: No, the first string in the array is the items key; the rest would be the keys of the nested object. The odd thing with the object is that it could contain more than one key.

Comment: @Bergi Its normal, because it can contain more than one key. Friends on the server side is an object, and being an object it should be able to hold just as many keys, as it should be able to hold many sub entries, which themselves can be objects, arrays, or simple entries. Think pure JSON. Take a complex collection of complex objects, serialize it to normal JSON, and remove the keys. How would you be able to represent that in a standard way that works everywhere without having to resort to deduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that does what I think you want:

```
function keyValuesToObject(keys, values) {
    var obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var value = values[i];
        obj.push({});
        for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
            var key = keys[j];
            if (typeof key === "object") {
                for (var k in key) {
                    obj[i][k] = keyValuesToObject(key[k], value[j]);
                }
            }
            else {
                obj[i][key] = value[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

It does not handle malformed input, so you might want to put checks in there depending on how you plan to use it.

You can see it in action on [this online jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FPTLM/1/).

By the way, the key and value value arrays you gave had mismatched opening and closing brackets, so I had to fix them.

Comment: Wow, that was insanely fast, kudos to you ! I would have spent hours trying to solve that puzzle, mucho Gracia !

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that i put up a test page showing how your implementation is being used : https://github.com/itechnology/JsonRaw thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPAHW/)

```
function pairUpItem(keys, values) {
    var len = keys.length;
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        var value = values[i];
        if (typeof(key) == "string") {
            result[key] = value;
        } else {
            for (var key2 in key) {
                if (key.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
                    result[key2] = pairUpItems(key[key2], value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function pairUpItems(keys, values) {
    var len = values.length;
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var value = values[i];
        if (typeof(value) !== "undefined") {
            result.push(pairUpItem(keys, value));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var keys   = ["Age", "Name", "Photos", { "Friends": ["FirstName", "LastName"] }];
var values = [ [31, "Bob", ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"], [ ["Bob", "Hope"], ["Foo", "Bar"] ] ], [21, "Jane", ["4.jpg", "5.jpg"], [ ["Mr", "T"],["Foo", "Bar"] ] ] ];

var result = pairUpItems(keys, values);
​console.dir(result);​
```

Comment: Hats off to both of you. It always amazes me how some ppl do this kinda stuff with ease. I'm good with deduction & boolean logic, but that's about it ! :) I really admire those algorithmic skills.